# Substituting password parameter value in bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash, passwords

I have a script running on a Linux box that reads commands and calls a program on certain events.

We need to log these commands, but filter/substitute the password parameter when it is used by putting in five Xs in a row (XXXXX).

**Example of input**

The input received by the bash script has a command type followed by various parameters and looks like these examples:

- `adduser --username="foo" --password="bar"`
- `remove --username="foo"`
- `listusers`
- `changepass --username="foo" --password="bar"`

The basic format is `command parameter="" parameter=""...`

**Example of logged value**

The above values would look like this in a log:

- `adduser --username="foo" --password="XXXXX"`
- `remove --username="foo"`
- `listusers`
- `changepass --username="foo" --password="XXXXX"`

**What I have tried**

I tried to use bash substitution but in the first case, we were not quoting the passwords (we later found out that this would be passed with quotes). It would cut off everything after the password. The second option just does not do the substitution at all.

- `echo "${value%password=*}password=XXXXXX" >> somelog.log`
- `echo "${value/password=\"(.*?)\"/password=xxxxx }" >> somelog.log`

I feel like the second option is close, but I am missing something. If anybody can direct me on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your problem implies another problem; are you passing `$value` to `eval`? I would suggest modifying the script so that `value` is actually an array such as `cmd=(adduser --username="foo" --password="bar")`. You'd then execute with `"${cmd[0]}" "${cmd[@]1:}"`, and log with `${cmd[@]/password=*/password="XXX"}`; the substitution is applied to each array element separately, not the entire command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a requirement to do this natively in bash?

It would probably be easier to just pipe through sed. but if you want to use bash I'd suggest the following to change anything prefixed with --password= followed by anything non-space (so it catches quoted and unquoted passwords). I used // in case multiple instances of --password on one line are a requirement. extglob (extended pattern matching) needs to be turned on in your script for this to work.

```
shopt -s extglob
"${value//--password=+([! ])/--password=XXXXX }"
```

References:
   http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern
   http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#search_and_replace

Testdata:

```
adduser --username="foo" --password="bar"
adduser --username="foo" --password=bar
remove --username="foo"
listusers
changepass --username="foo" --password="bar" --something="else"
changepass --username="foo" --password="bar" --something="else" --password="again"
```

Turns into:

```
adduser --username="foo" --password=XXXXX
adduser --username="foo" --password=XXXXX
remove --username="foo"
listusers
changepass --username="foo" --password=XXXXX  --something="else"
changepass --username="foo" --password=XXXXX  --something="else" --password=XXXXX
```

Edit: I forgot to mention extglob needs to be activated for this.

Comment: My bad, I wanted to and forgot. thanks for pointing that out, I'll add it back in.

Comment: This is much better than my answer (and my attempts at getting lookbehind to work).

Comment: When I just tried your example, my output keeps the password in plain text. 

So basically, you are looking for one or more characters that are not a space? Sorry, my regex reading is not as great as it should be so if I am wrong about the interpretation, please feel free to correct me. I think we run into an issue because there is not always a space after the password value.

Comment: Bash pattern matching used in string replacements not "real" regex, so don't feel bad if it looks hard to read (normal regex can be hard enough at times).  Is your data somewhere different than the testdata I used? I forgot to mention that extglob needs to be active and added that to my answer later, so that may also have been missing when you tested.

Comment: shopt -s extglob fixed the issue. You are correct. 

I am accepting the sed answer because it is so simple. But I will upvote your answer. You provided an awesome explanation and I verified it works. Thanks!

Comment: I switched to this answer after seeing the other comments. It addresses that nasty `--password="foo\"bar"` case quite well. Thanks.

Comment: What about `--password="foo bar"`, or worse, `--password=" foobar"`? The pattern doesn't distinguish between quoted spaces and the space that actually terminates the argument.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not fond of bash substitution and prefer using sed for a task like this. What about :

```
echo "$value"|sed 's/password="[^"]*"/password="XXXXX"/' >> somelog.log
```

?

Comment: Not quoting `"$value"` loses whitespace information and expands globs/etc. and the sed pattern fails for escaped double quotes in the password string.

Comment: This is simply not as robust as RSchulze's answer as well as being more costly (as it requires a sub-shell and an external process). This fails for a password value of `--password="foo\"bar"` for example.

Comment: You're right, @EtanReisner, RSchulze's is more robust and efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Shell replacement expansions are patterns not regular expressions.

Use `"${value/password=\"*\"/password=XXXXX}"` but note that that will be greedy (but you can't avoid that with this method) though it appears to handle escaped quotes inside the password string

If you need to worry about later arguments then you need to use something else (that can do a regular expression).

Something like:

```
[[ "$f" =~ (.*password=)\"[^\"]*\"(.*) ]]; echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}XXXXX${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
```

but this has problems with escaped quotes (it ends the match early).

But RSchulze's answer is better.